# Batch Script Required to display Windows Services Path

Tags: windows, cmd

I require a batch script, which can display the "Path Addresses", to all services running on my windows machine.

Any pointers / suggestions could be of great of help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a batch file.

You can get the list from the registry

```
reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services /s /v ImagePath
```

Or from WMI

```
wmic service get name, pathname
```

Comment: WMIC can't be used in Windows XP with lower privileges!, though you are right.